# Force stop WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

On Ubuntu 18.04 server, I start ESB profile using "sudo wso2ei-6.5.0-integrator" successfully. But after restarting my server then I can not start the ESB profile again. The error log as bellow:

```
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,743] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,744] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,745] [EI-Core]  WARN - PassThroughHttpListener System may be unstable: HTTP ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processSessionRequests(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:243)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:146)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:349)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,753] [EI-Core]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,753] [EI-Core]  WARN - PassThroughHttpSSLListener System may be unstable: HTTPS ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processSessionRequests(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:243)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:146)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:349)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,766] [EI-Core] ERROR - AbstractProtocol Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9763"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:475)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:745)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:467)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1007)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.startConnectors(CarbonTomcat.java:429)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.transport.ServletTransportManager.startTransports(ServletTransportManager.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:199)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:317)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.registerThrottlingAgent(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.internal.ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.activate(ThrottlingAgentServiceComponent.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:220)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5433)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-10-19 00:03:33,768] [EI-Core] ERROR - CarbonTomcat LifeCycleException while starting tomcat connector
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-9763]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.startConnectors(CarbonTomcat.java:429)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.transport.ServletTransportManager.startTransports(ServletTransportManager.java:78)
```

I think the ESB profile is running, but I can not access the carbon server. I also search on google and try to force stop the service by "sudo wso2ei-6.5.0-integrator stop" or "sudo sh integrator.sh stop" and start it again but still not successfully. 
Could you please help me to start the ESB profile again?

Comment: You can get the PID of the server and kill it. 

For eg:- in linux

ps aux | grep wso2
sudo kill -9 <PID_OF_WSO2EI>

Comment: Maybe if you kill the process java is possible restart again. ```killall java```

Comment: The problem was solved by killall java. Thanks @mleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to solve my problem.
- Get the PID of the server: sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8280
- Kill the process: kill pidport
Hope this helps. Thanks!